# video not refreshing when using OpenCV in python

Tags: python, opencv

I am using the openCV module in python, for capturing video from the webcam of my laptop. I am getting some unusual behaviour. The below is the code that i am using

```
class bnw_video() :

    def __init__(self) :

        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.cap.set(3,320)
        self.cap.set(4,240)
        self.start_video()

    def start_video(self) :

        while(True) :
            ret,frame = self.cap.read(0)
            cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
            time.sleep(0)

bnw_video()
```

I am using the above code to display the video actively captured by the webcam. When the time.sleep value is 0, the video is displayed perfectly. But if the time.sleep value is 0.1, the video just displays one frame, and then stops.

I dont understand why this is hapenning.

Comment: shouldn't you also add a waitKey(int ms) after imshow? probably replacing time.sleep

Comment: @Miki how does that help ?

Comment: actually refreshing the drawing event queue. At least this is how it works in C++. Can you give it a try?

Comment: @Miki i tried and it worked. Thanks a lot. But could you explain what does refreshing the drawing event queue mean, and why would my program not word without it ?

Comment: posted an answer with an explanation. I don't know enough of internal OS events to provide a better answer. Though, the important thing to remember is to always call `waitKey` when you want refresh windows created with `imshow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `cv2.waitKey(delay_in_ms)`, instead of `time.sleep(...)`.

From OpenCV [doc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#waitkey):

> This function is the only method in HighGUI that can fetch and handle events, so it needs to be called periodically for normal event processing unless HighGUI is used within an environment that takes care of event processing.

If you don't call `waitKey`, the windows content (created by `imshow`) won't be refreshed.